# Alternatives to MySql Query Browser?

Tags: mysql

I have been using the *MySql Query Browser* and [opinion]it has to be the worst UI that I've seen for anything. Ever.[/opinion] But it's free, so it's **great and I love it.**

Can anybody recommend any better, free tools for MySql DB admin? I want it to run on my local machine and not in a browser, if possible...

**Edit:** I'm on Windows, but if something works on OSX, Windows and Linux, that would be great...

**Edit:** I chose a best answer based on my preference after testing. Navicat (PC, Mac, Linux) was best, HeidiSQL is great too (perhaps more complete, but the UI is a bit clumsier), and the rest are relatively annoying (again, for what I need in a UI)... this is pretty subjective, but I think if you try them **all** as I did, you'll agree with my top two choices.

**Edit:** After actually trying them out working, HeidiSQL is the best. Again, it's my opinion...

Comment: Have a look at Query Builder tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Try free Express Edition.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go for [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/). It's free, easy to use and does practically everything you may think of.

Comment: Kind of enjoying Navicat more.

Comment: Now under closer examination, HeidiSQL is cooler. Much cooler.

Comment: Link is broken, try this: http://www.heidisql.com/.

Comment: is heidisql a relible alternative to navicat

Answer (score 7):

What platform do you intend this for?

There's sort of a rule that MySQL GUI clients must all be buggy, but **[navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)** is still much more reliable than MySQL Query Browser in my experience. (Just get the free edition.)

Comment: Navicat is working perfectly. I'll vote you up tomorrow when I get my points again.

Comment: On linux, navicat comes with its own instance of WINE inside the insallation zip/tar file. Thus, there may be potential for conflicts with other WINE instances  already installed on the linux system (... I just tested it. It IS indeed possible to run more than one WINE app at the same time with navicat running, but this does may not necessarily hold for the WINE app that YOU want)

Comment: navicat- the lite edition is severely limited IMHO (the query builder is a text input window with very few productivity features enabled  - drag+drop is disabled, for example)

Comment: +1 for navicat. I've tested navicat and heidisql. The sync feature of navicat is really fantastic (if your tables are using primary indexes). But the data synchronization is only available in standard edition > $129. The second thing is the import of a huge sql file. HeidiSQL does not respond until the import is hopefully finished. With navicat this problem does not occur. But its not easy to find the right option. I found it through this faq: http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/How_do_I_import_SQL_file_into_the_Server%3F

Answer (score 4):

I get by with the community edition of sqlyog from www.webyog.com.

Comment: I'll try it though it's really NagWare and it's only windows...

Comment: It's annoying as a UI, but I upvoted you because it is a good answer.... :)

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Toad for MySQL](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql/Overview.htm), I think it is pretty good (only Windows though).

Comment: Windows only and pretty annoying in my tests/opinion. Thanks for your answer, though!

Answer (score 2):

Two very worthy contenders:

[Oracle SQLDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) (yes, made by Oracle, but works with MySQL and is free)

[DBVisualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/) (paid version is superb esp. for keyboard-shortcut jockeys, but there is a free version too)

Comment: Nice! I'll check out the Oracle one for sure.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Squirrel](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) is a very nice Swing client for any relational database that has a JDBC driver.  I think it's pretty good, and it's free.

Comment: I'll try it only to make sure that there are no good apps in Swing... :)

Comment: I upvoted you because it's probably a good GUI if you are already using JDBC, but since it's not MySql-specific it is missing things from the get-go (like being able to list the DBs). Plus, it is a typical Swing app, more for devs than users.

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) is a nice free tool. [Querious](http://www.araelium.com/querious/) also looks good, although it's still in beta (and not free).

Comment: +1 Great, I'll check them out.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: another solution could be to use [OpenOffice Base](http://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html) and [connect to the MySQL DB](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Connect_MySQL_and_Base#MySQL_settings) (it's similar to connect a MS Access file to MySQL), except that OpenOffice is free.

But I think [using HeidiSQL suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/395570/260080) is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Jet Profiler is great for analyzing/optimizing queries

Answer (score 0):

Try the [SQLYog MySQL GUI](http://www.webyog.com/en/index.php).  The community edition is free and has proven to be more than adequate for what I need.

Comment: we already have that in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I use [DbVisualizer Free edition](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/download/install.jsp).  Cross platform, nice gui, easy to use.